# How to turn ON/OFF https during the Azure release?

Tags: azure, azure-devops, azure-powershell

I would like to turn ON/OFF HTTPS Only of my website during the pipeline execution.

[image]

```
Set-AzWebApp -ResourceGroupName $(ResourceGroupName) -Name $(WebAppName) -HttpsOnly $flase
```

I am using private windows agent.

[image]

I am getting following issue
[image]

I have Az installed on my server.

Could you please help me?

Answer (score 0):

> To use Azure ClI task you need to follow below prerequisites
>
> - A Microsoft Azure subscription
> - Azure Resource Manager service connection to your Azure account
> - Microsoft hosted agents have Azure CLI pre-installed. However **if you    are using private agents, [install Azure CLI](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/cli/azure/install-azure-cli) on the
>   computer(s) that    run the build and release agent.** If an agent is
>   already running on    the machine on which the Azure CLI is installed,
>   restart the agent to    ensure all the relevant stage variables are
>   updated.

According to your error log, seems Azure CLI is either not installed properly or detected by Azure DevOps.

Please make sure you have restarted the build agent to ensure all the relevant stage variables are updated.

Besides, you could also try to use Azure CLI on the private agent directly check if you are able to use above Azure command to turn off https. This will also narrow down your issue.

Comment: If I use build in agent I got different error: "Script failed with exit code: 1". It is ubuntu.

Comment: @cashmere Thanks for your kindly update. I'm not so familiar with Azure infrastructure. Are you able to use your code/script locally to turn ON/OFF https. Could the issue is related to script. This will help to narrow down if issue related to Azure DevOps pipeline side.

Comment: I can use locally.

Comment: Hi cashmere,  could you give a try with this CLI command. `az webapp update --resource-group <YourResourceGroupName> --name <YourWebAppName> --set HttpsOnly=true` Check if this turn on https during pipeline.